# How to use template in <p-datatable>

Tags: angular, datatable, angular2-template, primeng

I've got a very basic question which I can't answer myself because most links to http://www.primefaces.org/primeng don't work anymore.
I also tried registering to their forum but their activation mail never arrives.

I use Angular2 and have a datatable with two columns: filename and status.
The status column I want to change. It holds now a number from 1 to 4 and I want to show a glyphicon based on the status.

I now have this, which is working:

```
<p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [value]="files" selectionMode="single"  sortField="Status" [sortOrder]="-1">
  <p-column field="FileName" header="Naam" sortable="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="Status" header="Status" sortable="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I tried this, just to test the templating but nothing changes:

```
<p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [value]="files" selectionMode="single"  sortField="Status" [sortOrder]="-1">
  <p-column field="FileName" header="Naam" sortable="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="Status" header="Status" sortable="true">
    <template let-file="rowData">
        {{file.Status == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"}}
    </template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

So save to conclude I'm not using it properly.

We're using PrimeNG 1.0.0-beta.16

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each `p-column` can have two templates - `body` and `header`, you should specify which one it is. It's not mandatory because `body` is default I think and this is what you need in this case, but it's good practice. You also need to add `pTemplate` to template in order for `p-column` to use it, this is the reason `p-column` won't display template you provided. So, your code should look like this:

```
<p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [value]="files" selectionMode="single" sortField="Status" [sortOrder]="-1">
  <p-column field="FileName" header="Naam" sortable="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="Status" header="Status" sortable="true">
    <ng-template let-file="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        {{file.Status == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"}}
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Defining a pTemplate with type property is deprecated use pTemplate="type" instead. In this example, use pTemplate="body"

Comment: Newer versions uses `ng-template` to avoid collisions.

Comment: What if I do not have an array of object, rather an array of Strings or numbers. How can I bind that ?

Comment: @gilhanan Can you please refer a few sources where I can learn a little more about what pTemplate is, where do we use it and what are it's possible values? I've been trying to google about pTemplate for a few hours now, but I can't find any particular source which clearly explains what it is.