# primeNg data table: p-column execute function inside "field" attribute?

Tags: angularjs, primeng

I am using `primeNg` library, I don't want to use a for loop inside my angular component to format my date from String to date, is there a way we can directly call component function inside `p-column`

```
<p-column field="new Date(createdDate)" [header]="'InputLabel.hold_date_text' | translate"></p-column>
```

`new Date` inside `p-column` doesn't work. is there a way arround

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please click on the 'primefaces' tag below your question. Read the text that about the tag that appears. Do you actually use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call function in field attribute. If you want, then you could use [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404838/how-to-use-template-in-primeng-datatable) like this below way

```
 <p-column field="createdDate" header="Create Date" >
            <template let-col let-appdt="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                <span>{{new Date(appdt[col.field])}}</span>
            </template>
        </p-column>
```